# Get view created using inflater.inflate

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I dont understand this. I cant setText() on view created using inflater.inflate()

```
val justView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mybutton, null, false)
ayatList.addView(justView)
justView.setText("OK")
```

Comment: Show the layout file, mybutton ?

Comment: Could you please add the error you're getting as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the result to `TextView` (assuming that that layout is just a `TextView`—note that `Button` is a type of `TextView`):

```kotlin
val justView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mybutton, null, false) as TextView
ayatList.addView(justView)
justView.setText("OK")
```